# Connect Four Diagonal Check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a function to check diagonal win in connect four. Already done with vertical and horizontal checks. I am adding a class to my class .slot with "player1" or "player2" depending on the var currentPlayer. I have an array of all possible combinations to victory and I am iterating over the combinations  and setting a counter. But the counter doesn´t goes up. I run out of ideas whats happening there. Not sure if it has to do with jQuery and the way I am iterating, but otherwise I got an error.
Someone sees the error in the function?

```
var combinations = [
    [$(".hole").eq(2), $(".hole").eq(9), $(".hole").eq(16), $(".hole").eq(23)],
    [$(".hole").eq(1), $(".hole").eq(8), $(".hole").eq(15), $(".hole").eq(22)],
    [$(".hole").eq(8), $(".hole").eq(15), $(".hole").eq(22), $(".hole").eq(29)],
    [$(".hole").eq(0), $(".hole").eq(7), $(".hole").eq(14), $(".hole").eq(21)],
    [$(".hole").eq(7), $(".hole").eq(14), $(".hole").eq(21), $(".hole").eq(28)],
    [$(".hole").eq(14), $(".hole").eq(21), $(".hole").eq(28), $(".hole").eq(35)],
    [$(".hole").eq(6), $(".hole").eq(13), $(".hole").eq(20), $(".hole").eq(27)],
    [$(".hole").eq(13), $(".hole").eq(20), $(".hole").eq(27), $(".hole").eq(34)],
    [$(".hole").eq(20), $(".hole").eq(27), $(".hole").eq(34), $(".hole").eq(41)],
    [$(".hole").eq(12), $(".hole").eq(19), $(".hole").eq(26), $(".hole").eq(33)],
    [$(".hole").eq(19), $(".hole").eq(26), $(".hole").eq(33), $(".hole").eq(40)],
    [$(".hole").eq(18), $(".hole").eq(25), $(".hole").eq(32), $(".hole").eq(39)]
];

function checkDiagonal() {
    for (var i = 0; i < combinations.length; i ++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < combinations[i].length; j++) {
            var count = 0;
            if (combinations[i][j].hasClass(currentPlayer)) {
                // console.log(combinations[i][j]);
                // console.log(count);
                count++;
                if (count == 4) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep resetting `count` to 0 before it can ever reach `4`, but you don't even need the line at all. Just remove the `else` block. Also, you don't need to list every combination manually, the next hole is always the current one plus 7.

Comment: That was one of my thoughts, but somehow doesn´t work either. Actually the solution below of Huw it works although it's kind of a manually for loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's not elegant to remove the *j* loop but I think it will work for you:

```
function checkDiagonal() {
  for (var i = 0; i < combinations.length; i ++) {
    const test1 = combinations[i][0].hasClass(currentPlayer);
    const test2 = combinations[i][1].hasClass(currentPlayer);
    const test3 = combinations[i][2].hasClass(currentPlayer);
    const test4 = combinations[i][3].hasClass(currentPlayer);
      
    if (test1 && test2 && test3 && test4) {
      console.log('diagonal win at i = ', i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.some` and `.every`:

```
function checkDiagonal() {
    return (combinations.some((combi, i) =>
                combi.every(cell => cell.hasClass(currentPlayer)));
}
```